# Exception thrown by 'stol' using Visual Studio but not gcc

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, visual-studio-2013, gcc4.9

The following code throws an exception when it is run under Visual Studio 2013 but not gcc 4.9.2.

The error reported is:

> 'exception: stol argument out of range'

`stol` returns a `long` so the size of `temp` should be big enough to hold the returned value.

Can anyone explain the behaviour. Is this possibly a compiler bug?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
    const std::string value = "4294967295";   // 0xffffffff

    try
    {
        int64_t temp = std::stol(value);
    }

    catch (std::invalid_argument& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "invalid_argument: " << ex.what() << "\n";
    }

    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "exception: " << ex.what() << "\n";
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could it be a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue? (i.e. compiling as 32 bit in VS, 64 bit in gcc?)

Comment: Did you try checking `sizeof(long)`

Comment: `long` is 32-bit on Windows, regardless of 32/64-bit VS compiler.

Comment: @Praetorian But the size of temp is 64 bits.

Comment: @ksl How does that matter? `stol` returns `long`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under Windows the type `long` is always 32-bits. Since `long` is a signed integer type this means that the range of `long` is between -2147483648 and 2147483647 inclusive. On Linux the size of `long` depends on whether you're compiling for 32-bits or 64-bits.

Since `std:stol` converts a string to `long` the result must fit into a `long`. If it doesn't then the function [throws `std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol#Exceptions). To resolve this problem you can use `std::stoll` which returns a `long long`, which is guaranteed to be at least 64-bits and so won't ever throw an exception when converting `"4294967295"`. You can also use `std::stoul`, which converts to a `unsigned long`, which is is guaranteed to have a range of at least 0 to 4294967295.

(Note that this is not strictly a Visual C++ versus GCC thing. When targeting Windows, GCC also always uses a 32-bit `long`.)

Answer (score 5):

My bet would be a 32 bits `long` on visual studio (max 2^31, so overflow) and a 64 bits `long` on GCC (so nowhere near overflow).

Comment: You can see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd86c16ecf24fc9e) Coliru g++ has `sizeof(long)` as 8.

Answer (score 3):

Not a compiler bug, the problem is your invalid assumptions.

The Standard allows `LONG_MAX` to be as low as 2147483647, so

> `stol` returns a `long` so the size of `temp` should be big enough to hold the value.

simply is not true.

Answer (score 1):

So just use `std::stoul` instead.

At first glance the string constant certainly exceeds the maximum value a `long` can assume, but not the max value an `unsigned long` can have...

Answer (score 0):

From

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol

strtol returns a long and you need strtoll to get a long long

Comment: That's not (necessarily) the whole picture, the real problem is the `sizeof(long)` as others have mentioned.